# To check similarity between text data

Tags: cluster-analysis, similarity, measure

Please guide me how to measure similarity of  text data for clustering, for numeric data we can measure with euclidean distance measure or any other distance measure. The data is  keywords used for searching collected from website and the second data set is the collection of snippets returned of some searching. the similarity should be similar in meaning as well.

Comment: Read **any book on text mining**. Or answer would be as long as this book.

Answer (score 0):

Read about tf–idf and cosine similarity.